# Accessing Razor Shared View Dll from GAC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorgenerator

I compiled my shared views as a separate dll(EmbeddedViews.dll) and was able to access in MVC 4 Project. Now i registered the shared view(EmbeddedViews.dll) Dll into GAC(Global Assembly Cache ) and trying to access the shared view in MVC4 project. It could not find the location of the view. I added the namespace of the dll in Web.config of the MVC4 project view. 
Is it possible to access the dll from GAC? or is there a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in Razorgenerator MVC. It is allowing me to render shared content across different projects by making a DLL. But I m not sure if this is the best way of doing.